# Find the indicated submatrix? (Simple, I'm missing something obvious)

Tags: linear-algebra

So I'm presently looking through my professor's notes and I cannot figure out for the life of me the sub matrix. I've never seen a matrix where there is a horizontal line through it like this.

> **Identify the indicated submatrix** $$ A = \left[\begin{array}{rrr|r} 0 & 1 & -7 & -5\\ 7&-1&0&2\\ \hline 2 & 5 & -2 & 0\end{array}\right]$$
> Find $A_{12}$.

Comment: Is it easier than I think? Is it basically go to the matrix at row 1 and column 2 and that is your answer? So in this case [-5 2]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think they intend: You can break $A$ into four submatrices of size $2\times3$, $2\times1,$ $1\times3$, and $1\times1$. Which one is $A_{12}$?